# How to use jicai q2 POS Thermal Printer (Sunmi V1) using asp.net web based application?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a web based application and I am able to run it inside Android Browser App and now My Client want it to use it on Jicai Q2 POS Device, App is running fine but I can't Print it from Jicai Q2 POS Thermal Printer(Guess it is Similar to Sunmi V1). I want it to print it via asp.net and Javascript to connect to the device, can any one able to help me ? I am new to this development

Answer (score 0):

I was able to print in jicai thermal printer passing Esc/Pos commands to the BluetoothSocket.OutputStream:

```
using Android.Bluetooth;

// First you get the BluetoothAdapter:
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
// then, you get the device:
BluetoothDevice device = adapter.BondedDevices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Address.Equals("00:11:22:33:44:55"));
// now you create the socket
BluetoothSocket socket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(Java.Util.UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
// and now, you're able to get OOS:
Stream outputStream = socket.OutputStream;

// then, you can send esc/pos commands:
var command = new byte[] { 0x0A }; // example line feed command
outputStream.Write(command, 0, command.Length);
```

Also, you can choose to use the lib that they provide, like in this [example](https://github.com/shangmisunmi/SunmiPrinterDemo).

I hope it helps.